# Pass json response to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is it possible to pass JSON response to a function?

Here is what I tried (refer below)

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//start for #send click function
$("#send").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: 'test.php',
     data: { request_id : '1' },
     type: 'post',
     success: function(e){
        window['test'](e);
     } 
    });
});
//end of #send click function
});

function test(e){
 $.each(e, function(index, value){
   alert(value.name);
 });
}
```

and here's what I get using 'console.log(e)

> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle =
>   doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|[]/\])/g, idRx =
>   /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/;
>   doc.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(refStyle); function
>   toggle(a) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}; if ('sf-dump-compact' ==
>   s.className) { a.lastChild.innerHTML = '▼'; s.className =
>   'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == s.className) {
>   a.lastChild.innerHTML = '▶'; s.className = 'sf-dump-compact'; }
>   else { return false; } return true; }; return function (root) { root =
>   doc.getElementById(root); function a(e, f) { root.addEventListener(e,
>   function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else
>   if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); }
>   }); }; root.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) { if ('' !=
>   refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover',
>   function (a) { if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { refStyle.innerHTML =
>   'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF
>   !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } }); a('click', function (a, e) {
>   if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if
>   (!toggle(a)) { var r =
>   doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s =
>   r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode;
>   t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f =
>   f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t =
>   t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) {
>   r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc,
>   '\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if ('sf-dump-compact' == r.className) {
>   toggle(s); } } } }); var indentRx = new
>   RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || '
>   ').replace(rxEsc, '\$1')+')+', 'm'), elt =
>   root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, t = []; while
>   (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP');
>   len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); root = t;
>   len = t.length; i = t = 0; while (i < len) { elt = root[i]; if ("SAMP"
>   == elt.tagName) { elt.className = "sf-dump-expanded"; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a =
>   doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref';
>   elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; }
>   a.innerHTML += '▼'; a.className += '
>   sf-dump-toggle'; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) {
>   toggle(a); } } else if ("sf-dump-ref" == elt.className && (a =
>   elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a;
>   if (/[[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a !=
>   elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { t = a.nextSibling;
>   elt.appendChild(a); t.parentNode.insertBefore(a, t); if
>   (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += '
>   ▶'; } else { elt.innerHTML =
>   '▶'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className
>   += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className =
>   'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } ++i; } }; })(document);  
>   pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; }
>   pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact {
>   display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border:
>   none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor:
>   pointer; border: 0; outline: none; }pre.sf-dump{background-color:#fff;
>   color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco,
>   Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;
>   position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}array:7 [   "_token" => "7XZ28j53YXrmlVXQVVdX2KSfrf1IiX080lSnrdD2"   "log_schedule" => ""   "break_time" => ""   "grace_time" => ""   "lunch_schedule" => ""   "workday_schedule" => ""   "employee_id" => "MMPH15-0160" ]
>   Sfdump("sf-dump-735817620")

but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any help, clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations please?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement, and "Is it possible" is not a real question.  Instead, state the actual behavior you are getting, including the exact wording of any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: `it doesn't work` isn't helpful description of the problem

Comment: please see my updated post.

Comment: @Tushar: what guess?

Comment: What happens if you change window['test'](e); to console.log(e) and then check in your window console?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: please see my updated post.

Comment: @CodeDemon - what does your test.php do? Are you able to supply that code as well?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Can you please describe your issue? Maybe there are some other way of solving what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: its the server side script

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: as you can see on my post above, im trying to pass the json response unto a global function.

Comment: @CodeDemon - sorry for me that does not make sense at all. It's hard to give recommendations if we don't know what the actual issue is. I believe you are not able to pass a js-function and use it from the server response because that seems like what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML and jquery**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Ajax Responce
        </title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
//start for #send click function
                $("#send").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'test.php',
                        data: {request_id: '1'},
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: test
                    });
                });
//end of #send click function
            });

            function test(e) {                
                //var data=$.parseJSON(e);

                console.log(e);
                $.each(e, function (index, element) {
                    $('#txt').append(element+"<br>");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="send" name="bt" id="send" >
        <div id="txt"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
$res = $_REQUEST['request_id'];
$arr = array("id" => $res, "name" => "Testing", );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

your must need to json_encode array.
then it will parse in jquery.
in test function as you want to call it. after success of ajax.
try this... it will solve ur problem.

Comment: assume that I have already a serve side script that sends me the json response.

Comment: you have to check what data are you geting from server.. in console,  you can simply add  dataType: 'json',  and remove..  parse.json functin.. only check first your output of server must be a object.    you must add   dataType: 'json', .. see my updated ans

Comment: Yes, I checked it through console and I see it has a response (no error)

Comment: insert in test function.. console.log(e);  and check in console is it object. ?

Comment: see the error thrown from above post. First, I retrieved the response successfully but when I pass the response to the function, an error is thrown.

Comment: $.each function not geting proper object.. your server data must be a object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99657/discussion-between-nitesh-pawar-and-code-demon).

Answer (score 0):

@CodeDemon there is an error with your window call which is why it is dumping out HTML etc. Is there a reason for the window call vs the code below. I'd test the basic e.g. below, and if that works and then expand the troubleshooting:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        function test(e){
            console.log('Peak into e', e);
            if (e !== undefined && Object.keys(e) > 0) {
             $.each(e, function(index, value){
               alert(value.name);
             });
            } else {
               alert('something's wrong with e');
            }
        }

        //start for #send click function
        $("#send").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
             url: 'test.php',
             data: { request_id : '1' },
             type: 'post',
             success: function(e){
                test(e);
             } 
            });
        });
    //end of #send click function
    });
```

Comment: i tried the actual calling of the function e.g. test(e) and still no luck, error form above post

Answer (score 0):

Until you "parse" it, the response is just a string.  You need to use `JSON.parse(e).each...`

You can have jquery automatically convert the string to json but you have to tell it to.  look up jquery json response